# can't set a different filter in file:inbound-channel-adapter and scanner?

Tags: java, spring-integration

Below is part of my Spring Integration config :

```
<bean id="recursiveScanner" class="org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner" >
    <property name="filter" ref="skipTmpFileFilter" />
</bean>

<bean id="skipTmpFileFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="^[^~].*"/>
</bean>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="${inbound.folder}"
                              scanner="recursiveScanner" 
                              id="fileChannel" 
                              filter="fileNameFilter">
    <integration:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="10000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

As you can see, I'd like to define 2 different filters :

- one to skip temp files, in the recursiveScanner
- one more advanced in which I have defined some other patterns, fileNameFilter (details of which are not relevant, so I'm not providing it)

What I see when I launch this in debug mode is that first, skipTmpFileFilter is set in recursiveScanner, but it is overwritten by fileNameFilter a bit after, making skipTmpFileFilter ineffective.

Is it the intended behavior or a bug ? I think it would make sense to be able to configure 2 different filters, one generic (in scanner) and one more specific (in the inbound adapter). Here, I'm kind of forced to use a composite filter.

Thanks

Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take a look to the source code of `FileReadingMessageSource`, we'll see:

```
public void setFilter(FileListFilter<File> filter) {
    Assert.notNull(filter, "'filter' must not be null");
    this.scanner.setFilter(filter);
}
```

And there is no more stuff around the `filter` for the `FileReadingMessageSource`. Everything is delegated to the `DirectoryScanner`.

So, there is no any choice, unless provide only one `filter` option: or for the `DirectoryScanner` bean, or `<file:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

And yes: to have several filters in place you should use `CompositeFileListFilter`.

However I think we can protect that point of the **override** case.

Feel free to raise [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) issue on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer !JIRA created : https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3619